# Creating a scope in Ruby on Rails, that returns an instance of an object only if all the associated instances fit a certain condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table called Carts with a has_many relationship to another table called Subcarts. I want to create a scope that returns all instances of the Cart table where all the associated Subcarts fits a particular condition (ex: subcart.status == 1). If even one subcart that is associated to a Cart instance has a status of 1, the query should not return the cart instance.

```
scope :cart_bucket, -> {
   includes(:subcarts).
   where.not('subcarts.status = ?', 1).
   references(:subcarts)
```

I've also tried to use select within the query but had an error returned because of the return array data type. I would like to keep this within a scope and not create a method if at all possible.

Comment: What DB are you using? On Postgres this sounds like a job for a lateral join. Also `scope` is just a widely abused syntactic sugar for declaring class methods. Use it for simple oneliners. Don't use it for this job. Mulitline stabby lambdas are unreadible.

Comment: It is a postgrasql DB, I'll look into lateral joins. I'm trying to stick to an existing convention by using scope instead of using a method. But I get what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all the carts ids from those subcarts where the status is not 1 and use that as the `where` clause to leave out all the carts matching those ids:

```
Cart.where('NOT EXISTS (SELECT s.cart_id FROM subcarts s WHERE s.cart_id = carts.id AND s.status = 1)')
```

The ActiveRecord version might change a bit:

```
Cart.where.not(id: Subcart.where(status: 1).select(:cart_id))
```

There the SQL generated uses a `NOT IN` clause instead of `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: You can get the former with `Cart.where.not(Subcart.arel_table.project(Subcart.arel_attribute(:cart_id)).where(Subcart.arel_attribute(:cart_id).eq(Cart.arel_attribute(:id)).and(Subcart.arel_attribute(:status).eq(1))).exists)`